# Objective-C 'pass'

Tags: objective-c

Is there an equivalent of the python `pass` in objective-C?

```
if item == '4':
    pass
else:
    run_function()
```

In objective-C:

```
if (item == '4') {
    **pass**;
} else {
    run_function();
}
```

What would the `pass` be here?

Comment: maybe the empty block statement? Or `;`? Or just write `if (item != 4) { run_function(); }` and omit the `else` clause altogether?

Comment: There isn't a universal equivalent, because ObjC doesn't _require_ statements in certain places the way Python does. `@interface Strudel : NSObject @end`, for example, would be the equivalent to `class Strudel(object): pass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ([item isEqualToString:@"4"]) {
    ; //<- valid statement
} else {
    [self method];
}
```

this would be the same. I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler emits the exact same binary code

```
if ([item isEqualToString:@"4"]) {
} else {
    [self method];
}
```

and of cause semantical the same would be

```
if (![item isEqualToString:@"4"]) {
    [self method];
}
```

Comment: For readers, a comment `/* Do nothing */` or equivalent would be helpful if you really mean to `pass`. For that reason, the third option would be best for the specific example.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would just negate the condition:

```
if (item != '4') {
    run_function();
}
```